# getting a button to respond in size to responsive div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Google Map within a responsive `div` so that the map changes size depending on screen size, which is working perfectly. I also have a button above the map. I need this button to always be the same width of the map, is this possible?

My column:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <br />

    <p>
        <button style="width:60vh" formtarget="_blank"
            onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=@Model.OfficialSchoolName+@Model.Address1+@Model.County+@Model.Eircode')"
            type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Get Directions
        </button>
    </p>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

        <div id="map" class="embed-responsive-item"
            style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it looks currently at full screen size (perfect):

[image]

How it looks currently at small screen size (button is too large):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: Please **don't** use a button when its purpose is the same as an link / anchor. So please use an `<a href="…">` element and style it like a button.

The solution for your problem is to use relative sizes that doesn't depend on the screen size. You can use the following solution:

```html
<p>
    <a style="width:100%" href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=@Model.OfficialSchoolName+@Model.Address1+@Model.County+@Model.Eircode"
            class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Get Directions
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to replicate without having your google maps api key, however i would try and put the map and the button in the same div container and give the width of the button and map div the same percentage

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="button">
        <!-- button here -->
      </div>
      <div class="map">
        <!-- map here -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.button {
  width: 100%;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You will just then need to set the property of your button and map to 100% width as they will both be in their own containers

working example can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dust-7hkpz